# UITableViewCell rows changing their order unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a view in which I need to create expanded table. For that purpose I am using [SKSTableView](https://github.com/sakkaras/SKSTableView) and the view is as given below

[image]

As soon as table gets re loaded the order of rows is changing as shown below

[image]

Heading are rows here and rest data are subrows. Labels in this views are fixed but on right hand side all fields are being created programmatically. Code inside `cellForSubRowAtIndexPath` is shown below

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // Make cell unselectable
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        CustomTextField* tf;
        UIButton *button = nil;
        UISegmentedControl *segment = nil;
        [cell.textLabel setFont:FONT_OPENSANS_LIGHT(14)];
        [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        switch (indexPath.section) {
        //all fields area created here example for 1 of the field is
            tf = nameField_ = [self makeTextField:self.name placeholder:@"Sunil Joshi"];
                        [nameField_ setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
                        [cell addSubview:nameField_];


        }
       }


 - (CustomTextField *) makeTextField: (NSString*)text  placeholder:     (NSString*)placeholder  {
    CustomTextField *tf = [[CustomTextField alloc] init];
    tf.placeholder = placeholder ;
    tf.text = text;
    tf.font = FONT_OPENSANS_LIGHT(12);
    tf.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    tf.enabled = NO;
    tf.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return tf;
}
```

Please help me in finding the issue why these rows are changing their order.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your code, your cell is being reused and you are adding `UITextField` based on some condition.

```
[cell addSubview:nameField_];
```

As the cell is being is reused, the textField is shown in all cells. To overcome from these problem of showing `textfield` in all rows, you need to remove this `textField` from `view` and add again based on your condition.

Every time the cell is drawn the `textField` is getting added in cell.

Comment: Tried this and i am adding fields only after checking the condition properly. but unable to find the main issue for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to figure out the exact problem without viewing the whole source of the table creation.

But If I was to create such a page then I would have followed the following approach -

1) Create an instance of UITableView, set it's dataSource and delegates to the current view and adding it over the current view.
2) Create Personal Details and Contact Details as sections

```
typedef enum {
    PERSONAL_DETAILS_SECTION = 0,
    CONTACT_DETAILS_SECTION,
} kListType;

#pragma mark section creation related methods

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2; // Personal Details and Contact Details
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50.0f;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return nil;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return nil;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50.0)] autorelease];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];// set actual RGB

UIImageView *iconImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)] autorelease];
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:((section == PERSONAL_DETAILS_SECTION) ? @"pdimage.png" : @"cdimage.png")]];
            [view addSubview:imageView];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((5 *scalingFactor), (2 *scalingFactor), view.frame.size.width - (10 *scalingFactor), view.frame.size.height - (3 *scalingFactor))];
    label.text = ((section == PERSONAL_DETAILS_SECTION) ? @"Personal Details" : @"Contact Details");
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:(13.0f * scalingFactor)];

    [view addSubview:label];
    [label release];

    return view;
}
```

3) Create Cell's as follows -

```
#pragma mark cell creation related methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;// for both the section return one row 
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0f;

    if(indexPath.section == PERSONAL_DETAILS_SECTION)
        height = 120.0;
    else
        height = 100.0;

    return height;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if(indexPath.section == PERSONAL_DETAILS_SECTION) 
{
    static NSString * cellId = @"personalDetailCellId";

    cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
           cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

     // create instance of Name label and addict on the left side and it;s corresponding value label on then right side, customize, position and add them
     // create instance of Gender label on the left side and it's segment control on the right side, customize, position and add them
     // create instance of Age label on the left side and it's value label on the right side, customize, position and add them
     // create instance of Blood Group label on the left side and it's selection control on the right side, customize, position and add them
    }
    else
    {
    // cell is already created.
    }
  }
else // Contact Details Setion
{
    static NSString * cellId = @"contactDetailCellId";

    cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
           cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

     // create instance of Mobile Number label on the left side and it's corresponding value label on right side, customize, position and add them
     // create instance of Landline No label on the left side and it's corresponding value label on right side, customize, position and add them
     // create instance of Email Id label on the left side and it's corresponding value label on right side, customize, position and add them

    }
    else
    {
    // cell is already created.
    }
  }

return cell;
}
```

Note : By following above approach you can achieve your requirements. Also I have just written steps above, you need to write the code for the corresponding comments and customize them as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks for steps but there is no such creation time issues with my table here.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"someThingNew";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (!cell) {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
}
```

Try with this.

Comment: I am already doing this. Actually cell creation and loading data is not the issue. Issue is as soon as table is re loading it is reordering cell unexpectedly.