# How to remove & merge empty cells in UITableView using Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I am populating `UITableView` cell data from `Parse PFQueryTableViewController` and I am having certain constraints which are leave some cells empty in between. How do I remove the empty cells in between and merge them?

I'm doing something like this:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"ident";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if  (result == a) {                
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"ItemName"];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Price"];

        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [_itemPrefArray removeAllObjects];
        [_userPrefArray removeAllObjects];

    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        [_itemPrefArray removeAllObjects];

        [_userPrefArray removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

How can I modify the creation of the cell and create only inside the `if` condition and don't create in `else`?

Comment: Not sure what you are actually trying to achieve. Why don't you only create a cell when the condition is met?

Comment: Hi Eric! I am actually pulling data from Parse and showing up in custom PFQueryTableViewController. How can i create a cell and return within the same method ? i tried with a sample variable such as "id cell = nil" and tried doing but it's not working

Comment: At the end of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you should have a line returning a cell: `return cell;`. What you want, is to only return a cell when a condition is met, so move the return cell; line inside of the if-statement and get rid of the else.

Comment: Thanks Eric. i did that but this code is in between "[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * userData, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {   //creating cell } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: error setting cell data %@", error);
        }
    }];

Comment: Sorry if that's confusing.... here's is the actual code http://pastebin.com/mR5qFzdr

Comment: Okay, and what is your exact result if you are running this code?

Comment: I can't run as i am getting compile error while returning cell. I can't return cell inside "if" cause cellForRowAtIndexPath return type is cell.

Comment: I've tried doing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203647/uitableviewcell-rows-changing-their-order-unexpectedly      by creating  UITableViewCell *cell = nil; and doing this inside if loop cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];   and i am getting compilation error while assigning cell.